# Conditional Subsetting of a Nested List

Tags: r, list, nested, subset, run-length-encoding

I have a nested list where ach sub list has two lists. A simplified output of this list is below:

```
nested.list <- list(`1` = structure(list(lengths = c(325L, 18L, 1L, 7L, 1L, 
10L, 1L, 35L, 1L, 1L, 152L, 1L, 1L, 37L, 1L, 33L, 1L, 15L, 2L, 
1L, 47L, 1L, 29L, 107L, 35L, 3L, 6L, 12L, 16L), values = c(1, 
2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 129, 
1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1)), class = "rle"), `2` = structure(list(lengths = c(19L, 
99L, 1L, 16L, 2L, 24L, 1L, 12L, 1L, 23L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 51L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 34L, 1L, 15L, 1L, 20L, 1L, 8L, 1L, 18L, 28L, 7L, 105L, 
3L, 23L, 1L, 13L, 1L, 17L, 1L, 31L, 1L, 17L, 6L, 5L, 2L, 18L, 
1L, 20L, 2L, 38L, 21L, 9L, 2L, 89L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 26L, 4L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 1L, 7L, 1L, 24L), values = c(1, 2, 1, 2, 
1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 
2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 
2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2)), class = "rle"), 
    `3` = structure(list(lengths = c(6L, 3L, 14L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 9L, 2L, 29L, 3L, 11L, 1L, 19L, 1L, 20L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    22L, 11L, 2L, 1L, 7L, 2L, 17L, 30L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 8L, 4L, 
    5L, 1L, 23L, 1L, 11L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 29L, 2L, 10L, 1L, 17L, 
    6L, 12L, 1L, 22L, 22L, 8L, 3L, 2L, 13L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 83L, 
    1L, 24L, 1L, 24L, 1L, 7L, 6L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 37L, 1L, 32L, 
    33L, 5L, 1L, 29L, 6L, 7L, 16L, 2L, 16L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 
    18L, 1L, 9L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 21L, 14L, 12L, 1L, 33L), values = c(2, 
    1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 
    2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 
    1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 129, 1, 2, 1, 2, 
    1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 
    1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 
    2, 1, 2)), class = "rle"))
```

This was generated by `lapply(another.list, function(x) rle(x))` in case that is of importance.

Anyway, I know how to extract individual elements by doing something like `nested.list[[1]]["lengths"]`. However I am looking to conditionally subset each pair of lists so that I have all `lengths >= 6` and `values == 2`.

I have looked for previous answers and found examples such as `lapply(list,`[`, list$value == 2)`, but they do not extend to my case and I haven't been able to get them to.

I imagine there must be a simple way of doing this that I am missing.

Comment: do you need a data.frame

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a base R version which returns data.frames.

```
lapply(nested.list,function(x){
  y <- data.frame(lengths = x$length, values = x$values);
  y[y$lengths >= 6 & y$values ==2,]})
#$`1`
#   lengths values
#2       18      2
#4        7      2
#6       10      2
#...
#
#$`2`
#   lengths values
#2       99      2
#4       16      2
#6       24      2
#...
#
#$`3`
#   lengths values
#1        6      2
#3       14      2
#9        9      2
#...
```

Answer (score 1):

May be, we can do

```
lapply(nested.list, function(x)  {
    i1 <- x$lengths >=6 & x$values == 2
   within.list(x, {lengths <- lengths[i1]; values <- values[i1]}) })
#$`1`
#Run Length Encoding
#  lengths: int [1:9] 18 7 10 35 37 33 15 107 12
#  values : num [1:9] 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2

#$`2`
#Run Length Encoding
#  lengths: int [1:23] 99 16 24 12 23 51 34 15 20 8 ...
#  values : num [1:23] 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...

#$`3`
#Run Length Encoding
#  lengths: int [1:33] 6 14 9 29 11 19 20 22 7 17 ...
#  values : num [1:33] 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
```

---

If we want a data.frame as output in each `list`

```
lapply(nested.list, function(x) 
      subset(as.data.frame(unclass(x)), lengths >=6 & values == 2))
```

Answer (score 1):

Converting the class of `nested.list` from `list` to `data.table`, and subset values from the datatable.

```
library('data.table')
nested.list <- rbindlist(lapply(seq_along(nested.list), function(x) {
  y <- do.call('cbind.data.frame', nested.list[[x]])
  y$id <- x
  names(y) <- c('lengths', 'values', 'id')
  y}
  ))
out <- nested.list[lengths >= 6 & values == 2, ]
head(out)
#    lengths values id
# 1:      18      2  1
# 2:       7      2  1
# 3:      10      2  1
# 4:      35      2  1
# 5:      37      2  1
# 6:      33      2  1
```